# Programar tarea en Crontab para correr un archivo PHP

Tags: php, crontab

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando programar una tarea con Crontab Ubuntu. La tarea Cron consiste en ejecutar un archivo PHP y ese archivo tiene las instrucciones de  crear un archivo .txt y dentro del archivo escribir la palabra “hola”, para entender mejor lo que quiero hacer les anexo el código que tengo.
El problema que tengo es que el Cront no está ejecutando la tarea porque no aparece el archivo que se programó en el código de hola.php, pero cuando corro el archivo PHP con la instrucción php hola.php si crea el archivo example1.txt.

> Tarea Crontab

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/hola.php 2>&1
```

> Archivo hola.php que debería de ejecutar Crontab

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen("exaple1.txt", 'w+b') or die("Se produjo un error al crear el archivo");

  $texto = <<<_END
hola
_END;

  fwrite($fh, $texto) or die("No se pudo escribir en el archivo");

  fclose($fh);

  echo "Se ha escrito sin problemas";
?>
```

Espero que me puedan orientar a saber porque no esa ejecutando mi archivo PHP.

Saludos y excelente tarde.

Comment: Tu código debería funcionar. Lo único anormal que veo es que el archivo se llama **`exaple1.txt`** ¿Revisaste si ese archivo existe y tiene el contenido? Puede que estés revisando `example1.txt`

Comment: si ya cheque y no aparece en el directorio, notas otra cosa que sea que no este corriendo mi Crontab

Comment: Puedes intentar así: **`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/hola.php 2>&1`**  Supongo que habrás comprobado que la ubicación de `hola.php` que indicas ahí es correcta.